# How do I clean up my project structure so that files are committed correctly to my repository?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a folder on my laptop called `algo_trader/` which contains books, financial data, and notebooks. Here is a screenshot of my VSCode workspace:

[image]

`algo_trader/` is a folder that I use to learn the art of algorithmic trading.  Within it, I read code and write programs that test my understanding.

I wrote a notebook file called `broad_market_ema_vortex.ipynb` which you can see in the screenshot.  The cells within it aren't running properly, so I would like to commit this file to [this](https://github.com/kbs-code/algo_trader) Github repository.  I don't need to commit other folders so I added them to the `.gitignore`:

```
data/
ml_algo_trading_jansen_book/
algo_trader.code-workspace
../financial_data/
```

The files that will need to be pushed are `backtests/broad_market_ema_vortex.ipynb` and `setup.md`.

**Problem:**

I created a repository on Github (https://github.com/kbs-code/algo_trader).  Then within VSCode, I added the remote repository as depicted in this screenshot:
[image]

The `financial_data` source control repository that you see in the previous screenshot is incorrect.  It could be there because I added `financial_data` as a folder to my VSCode workspace.  `financial_data` is another folder on my laptop which has it's own separate Github repo, and it's helpful for me to refer back to it to use code I wrote previously.

When I tried to close this repository within VSCode, the only option after that was to reopen my closed repositories:

[image]

At this point, I can not push my notebook to Github because I am unable to correctly define the remote repository that I created as the source control repository.

How should I proceed?

Comment: easiest to do is to clone the github repo and copy/ **replace** the `.git` folder to your project folder

Comment: @rioV8 sorry, I don't understand.  What exactly should I be cloning?

Comment: you use github but have no clue what a cloned repo is, read up on `git clone`

Answer (score 0):

I navigated to `algo_trader/`  locally and ran `git init`.  After that, VSCode allowed me to push the files to the remote repository that I made earlier.  However, since `algo_trader` on Github was using the default branch called `main`, a second branch was created in Github called `master`.  I set `master` as default and deleted `main` and everything was in order.

[image]